# Can not download file java android

Tags: java, android, download

Why this code is not working?

```
public void onButtonClick2(View view)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        //tv.setText("This is download file program... ");

        try {
            URL website = new URL("http://sssemil.or.gs/users.ini");
            ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/users.ini");
            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        //tv.append("\nAnother append!");
        //this.setContentView(tv);
    }
```

First i tried to do as  here [Android: How to download file in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881774/android-how-to-download-file-in-android)
But it failed...

UPD:
logcat
http://pastebin.com/pUqmDfip

Comment: any errors in logcat?

Comment: While following the link, did you make use of an AsyncTask for downloading?

Comment: Post your errors.Be specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: logcat http://pastebin.com/pUqmDfip

Comment: Have a look at working code in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231511/how-to-download-a-file-and-get-the-path-location-locally/33231728#33231728